# Boost Library Link Failure

Tags: boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Linking CXX executable ../bin/decision_ensemble
  /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/decision_ensemble.dir/src/decision_ensemble.o: undefined reference to symbol 'boost::signals::connection::~connection()'
  /usr/bin/ld: note: 'boost::signals::connection::~connection()' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libboost_signals.so.1.46.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
  /usr/lib/libboost_signals.so.1.46.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anyone have this issue before?

My CMakeLists.txt has: `rosbuild_add_boost_directories()` added.

Call using boost bind:

```
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&DecisionEnsemble::ensembleCallback, &ensemble, _1, _2, _3));
```

I am trying to synch 3 messages containing a header with timestamp, a string and an int32.

Using the approximate example in the tutorials and various blogs out there have not helped.

Can anyone share there successful use of approximate time and CMakeLists.txt as an example to point me in the correct direction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52800/boost-library-link-failure/) by [101010](https://answers.ros.org/users/3108/101010/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2013-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-19**:
Which boost directories did you add using `rosbuild_add_boost_directories()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simply add:

```
rosbuild_link_boost(target lib1 lib2 lib3 ...)
```

to your CMakeList.txt, in your case:

```
rosbuild_link_boost( yourExecutableName signals )
```

---

Originally posted by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) with karma: 717 on 2013-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0